# Check replication type mysql

Tags: mysql, replication

I want to check the replication type for my master-slave setup that whether it is row based or statement based.. how can I do this? I am using mysql 5.6

Answer (score 19, accepted):

On the master, run:

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'binlog_format';
```

This variable will be either ROW, STATEMENT, or MIXED.

Note that the global default doesn't preclude individual sessions from changing their binlog format, and DDL statements are always logged in STATEMENT format regardless of what binlog_format is set to.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_binlog-format

Comment: I am facing some data drifting issues. Thanks to your answer, I checked that `binlog_format` on Master is `MIXED`; while on the Slave server it is showing as `ROW`. Is this problematic ?

Comment: Not a problem. The slave can understand any format it receives from its master. The `binlog_format` on the slave only controls the format of its own binary log.